# Bash script for few commands

Tags: bash, svn

Now we have a command `which_repo address/to/file.js` which detect what `svn` repo is used for the file and display answer on the screen. It looks like:

```
myrepo/address/to/file.js
```

after that I should type `svn blame cvs/myrepo/address/to/file`. End of the string I'm copying from the `which_repo` answer.

How to write the function which will perform this in a step, something like:

```
blame address/to/file.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a script `blame`:

```
#!/bin/bash
svn blame "cvs/$(which_repo "$1")"
```

Comment: Edited: Avoid backticks and added missing inner quotes.

Comment: Thank @AaronDigulla - what I submitted first was rather sloppy. :-)